# In LWUIT, how can i add multiple container/Layout on single Form?

Tags: forms, layout, java-me, lwuit

In J2ME I am Using LWUIT library.
My problem is I want to add various component on single Form using different layout or Container. I am looking for some code or example.

Example..

1. add Header image on top of the Form.
2. Adding two label, two textfield on
   one Container/layout and Two button
   on another Container/layout. Design
   like Login Form.
3. add Footer image on bottom of the
   Form.

Answer (score 3):

Set the title image of the form for showing header image. Set the `softbutton` image of the form for showing footer image.

Normally you can use the border layout or box layout for both container and form. See the LWUITDemo application on [LWUIT repository](http://java.net/projects/lwuit/sources/svn/show/trunk/Apps?rev=1504). It will helps you. Also see the same sample examples,

[The Lightweight User Interface Toolkit (LWUIT): An Introduction](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javame/lwuit_intro/)

[Using LWUIT layouts](http://lwuit.java.net/tutorial/layouts.html)

Answer (score 2):

use different container with different layout to add in form

i.e set form to `Borderlayout` add title container to north and footer container to south

next use another container with your required layout and add it to center in form, thus create container hierarchy

Comment: hi nirmal, Thanks for ur idea ,what an idea sirji.... Ur guidance help me lot. thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

For samples on how to arrange components in various layouts you can look within the LWUIT 1.5 distribution and on demos such as the LWUITDemo which has a layouts demo within it. Keep in mind that layouts can be nested.

The [LWUIT blog](http://lwuit.blogspot.com/) which I maintain contains lots of samples of layout usage.

Comment: What IDE is being in your blog?